# Gotting Error on spl token latest version

Tags: solana-program, token, spl

Previously, I was using SPL Token version 0.3.8 to mint tokens from the frontend. However, when I attempt to install the latest version(0.3.11), it returns an error.

```
ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined
    at ./node_modules/@solana/spl-token-metadata/lib/cjs/state.js (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:162901:40)
    at options.factory (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:467783:31)
```